# Alternative to WebBrowser control on Windows CE

Tags: c#, compact-framework, webbrowser-control

Welcome,
Has anyone know any alternative to WeBrowser control from .NET Compact Framework, which may be used with Windows CE? Unfortunately standard web control from .NET CF 2.0 doesn't work on WinCE. Is any way to present formatted text in embedded control in .NET CF application targeted to Windows CE?

Regards,
Grzegorz

Answer (score 2):

The Smart Device Framework used to have a browser control in it back in the 1.x days.  If you go to the [product page for the SDF](http://opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework/tabid/65/Default.aspx) you'll see links down at the bottom for all of the old source code.  Version 1.4 would probably be the best bet.  You could pull it and look in the OpenNETCF.Windows.Forms project for all of the source for that control.  It's been a long time, so I'm not certain it's non-WinMo compatible, but IIRC it was.

Comment: @Chris: Do you have an updated link? I've got to write some support for this on a legacy platform. If the WinCE WebBrowser control stays up, it eventually crashes the device because it consumes all of the available RAM (never empties cache, I think).

Comment: v. 1.4 source code is now available in the downloads section on Codeplex. https://opennetcf.codeplex.com/releases/view/618727

Answer (score 0):

The standard WebBrowser control is indeed available for .NetCF 2.0 in Windows CE, but you need to have the corresponding underlying items in your OS image. However, for the specific case of displaying rich text, the RichTextBox from Resco MobileForms Toolkit (http://www.resco.net/default.aspx) might help.